# How to make a pie chart for this data set?

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have data set in excel for which I need to show the value as a percentage of total.

```
Community | Number of Men | Total-Population
    A     |       5       |        20
    B     |       4       |        25
```

I need to create a pie chart that shows community A as the title and two sections one depicting 5 men as total of 20.

I am new to pivot charts so please help!

Answer (score 0):

Since you only want a pie chart involving `Community A` I do not see the point of having information pertaining to `Community B` in the question.

**Steps**

1. Store the information in excel as show in the picture below:
   [image: Store the information in excel]
2. Highlight the data and go to the insert tab and click the standard 2D pie chart button as shown in the image below:

[image: Highlight the data and go to the insert tab and click the the standard 2D pie chart button]

3. Double click on the title of the pie chart (A) and type in Community A as shown below:

[image: Update title]